# Join tstzrange in postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, join, merge

I have a table with a tstzrange, city and a boolean. Now I would like to merge values with the same boolean and city on consecutive days together. So for example I have

```
 city |                     date_range                          | bool 
-----+----------------------------------------------------------+--------
   berlin | ["2010-01-01 00:00:00+01","2010-01-01 00:00:00+01]  | True
   berlin | ["2010-01-02 00:00:00+01","2010-01-02 00:00:00+01"] | True
   berlin | ["2010-01-03 00:00:00+01","2010-01-03 00:00:00+01"] | False
   berlin | ["2010-01-04 00:00:00+01","2010-01-04 00:00:00+01"] | True
   paris  | ["2010-01-05 00:00:00+01","2010-01-05 00:00:00+01"] | True
   munich | ["2010-01-01 00:00:00+01","2010-01-01 00:00:00+01"] | True
   munich | ["2010-01-02 00:00:00+01","2010-01-02 00:00:00+01"] | False
```

Desired result would be

```
 city |                     date_range                          | bool 
-----+----------------------------------------------------------+--------
   berlin | ["2010-01-01 00:00:00+01","2010-01-02 00:00:00+01]  | True
   berlin | ["2010-01-03 00:00:00+01","2010-01-03 00:00:00+01"] | False
   berlin | ["2010-01-04 00:00:00+01","2010-01-04 00:00:00+01"] | True
   paris  | ["2010-01-05 00:00:00+01","2010-01-05 00:00:00+01"] | True
   munich | ["2010-01-01 00:00:00+01","2010-01-01 00:00:00+01"] | True
   munich | ["2010-01-02 00:00:00+01","2010-01-02 00:00:00+01"] | False
```

Notice that I don't want a query to output the desire result, but a function that actually adjust/merges the the tstzranges

Comment: Please post the actual output you want. Also post what have you tried.

Comment: @Belayer the output I want is after "Desired result would be". 
I tried with JOIN and MERGE but nothing worked for me.